# "ImportError: cannot import name Browser" with python mechanize

Tags: python, html, linux, forms, mechanize

I am unable to use a [mechanize code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hEAMNvbPgNzVxNmmDnLdGlVvQwypKhcpjAUAif1Jdkk/) ). The part that lead to the error is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
from mechanize import 
br = Browser()
```

I also tried

When executing it with python3.5, I find the following error:

```
# python mechanize.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mechanize.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mechanize import Browser
  File "/root/git/stakexchange-ask-question/mechanize.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mechanize import Browser
ImportError: cannot import name Browser
```

This is however precisely what is suggested by the official [mechanize website](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

If I modify the code to

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
br = mechanize.Browser()
```

I also get an error

```
   # python  mechanize.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mechanize.py", line 5, in <module>
    import mechanize
  File "/root/git/stakexchange-ask-question/mechanize.py", line 6, in <module>
    br =mechanize.Browser()
AttributeError: module 'mechanize' has no attribute 'Browser'
```

I have installed `mechanize` with

```
easy_install mechanize
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mechanize.Browser()?

Comment: `http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/` display a code that does not requires `from mechanize import Browser` to execute `mechanize.Browser()` but if `from mechanize import Browser` is removed, I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Browser'`

Comment: My answer was too fast. Be sure that you're not on Python < 3.X
http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html

Comment: You are right. Mine was python 2.7. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually in that case it should work. Before I wanted to say that you must have a python version inferior to 3., mechanize it not yet supported for this  version.

Answer (score 0):

The `python` version has to be at least `3.0` ([reference](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html))

Check your python version with

```
readlink -f $(which python) | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
```

But the error didn't came only from this. `mechanize` wasn't properly installed and I install it again from the [source code](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/download.html).